# Does netty support the MPEG-DASH protocol?

Tags: netty, mpeg-dash

nice to meet you.

The question is the title.

Does netty support the MPEG-DASH protocol?

Please answer my question. please.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short no... That said netty itself is a generic network framework which means you can add support for you custom protocol by implementing your own encoder / decoder.